# Создание класса в классе

Tags: php, функции, классы

Возможно ли создать `class` в `class`?

Пример:

```
<?php

class NameClass
{
    class NameClassTwo
    {
        ...
    }
}

?>
```

```
<?php

class::class::function(...)

?>
```

Возможно ли сделать что-то такое?
Или если нет, то есть ли альтернативные варианты?

А так же возможно ли сделать

```
<?php

function($type, function(...))
{
}

?>
```

?

Comment: Спрашивая "можно ли сделать что-то" надо всегда объяснять ЗАЧЕМ. Особенно спрашивая про "альтернативные варианты". Варианты всегда есть, но для этого надо знать, какую задачу ты решаешь.

Answer (score 2):

#### Вложенные и приватные классы - нет

> Возможно ли создать `class` в `class`?

Нельзя, PHP такой конструкции не позволяет, в отличие от Java. То же самое с видимостью классов - они всегда публичные, потому нельзя сделать классы `private` для их использования только внутри вашего неймспейса.

Если так надо обозначить класс, который обязательно должен быть внутренним, используйте префикс `Internal*`, так чисто семантически вы обозначите, что этот класс должен использоваться только в вашем коде.

#### Насчёт функций высшего порядка - да

Функцию высшего порядка можно сделать, без проблем, вот пример

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param callable $функция не принимает параметров
 * ...
 */
function функцияВысшегоПорядка($какой_то_параметр, $функция)
{
    // ...
    $функция(); // или call_user_func($функция);
    // ...
}
```

Вызывать эту функцию можно вот так

```
// с анонимной функцией
функцияВысшегоПорядка('что-то', function() { ... });

// передать метод объекта
функцияВысшегоПорядка('что-то', [$object, 'objectMethod']);
```